# Passing a for-each object to a sub or function in vba

Tags: vba, object, foreach

When I call the sub pFileName I get an 'object required' error with the following code:

```
Sub test()
Dim fs As Object
Dim csv As Object
Dim oFolder As Object

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = fs.getfolder(Application.CurrentProject.Path)

For Each csv In oFolder.files
    Debug.Print csv.Name
    pFname (csv)
Next csv
End Sub

Sub pFname(ByVal csv As Object)
    Debug.Print (csv.Name)
End Sub
```

I'm not sure why csv isn't considered an object - doesn't the Debug.Print statement right before the sub call prove it is an object?

Comment: Remove brackets. `pFname csv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the parentheses on this line:  `pFname (csv)`

Putting the parentheses around the parameter forces it to be passed `ByVal`, and you can't do that with an `Object`, because an `Object` basically *is* a reference.  This works just fine:

```
Sub test()
Dim fs As Object
Dim csv As Object
Dim oFolder As Object

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = fs.getfolder(Application.CurrentProject.Path)

For Each csv In oFolder.files
    Debug.Print csv.Name
    pFname csv  '<-----
Next csv
End Sub

Sub pFname(ByVal csv As Object)
    Debug.Print csv.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Great! That worked ... even though I specify "ByVal" in the function definition. I removed "ByVal" and it still works. I'll keep it this way but I only added "ByVal" because I saw an example of it somewhere.

Comment: @BrendanRafferty - `ByVal` and `ByRef` work the same way for objects, except that it passes the object `reference`  `ByVal` or`ByRef`.  I.e., if you pass an object as a `ByVal` parameter and set it to a new object inside the procedure, it won't effect the variable in the calling procedure.  If you pass an object as a `ByRef` parameter and set it to a new object, the variable in the calling procedure will also point to the new object.

Comment: @BrendanRafferty parameters are passed `ByRef` by default in VBA, but in an overwhelming majority of cases it's `ByVal` that makes more sense; there's a reason VB.NET and other languages pass parameters by value, by default.